Allure TestNG report shows 0 test cases run while the allure-results and allure-reports were generated successfully
I used Allure TestNG report for my tests. This is my pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>simtran</groupId>
    <artifactId>ATestPrj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <testng.version>7.10.1</testng.version>
        <allure.version>2.27.0</allure.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.22</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I run some sample tests, all the tests were run successfully and passed and the allure-results was generated successfully under the target folder as my configuration.
enter image description here
After running the command allure generate, the allure-report folder was generated successfully. I continue with the command allure open to open the test report. But on the report, it shows no information there with 0 test cases as below
enter image description here
Do I miss any steps to configure the allure report?
Please help me with this. I tried to figure it out but so far no luck. I appreciate any help!

I hope that you ran the allure serve command to view the reports
